# Why would anyone buy zombies?

Tags: magic, economy, zombies

In the shady city of Tarahan, ruled by the Cult of Carmine Heptagram, you can experience all sorts of arcane oddities, like hooded wraiths phasing through the buildings, stray imps being treated like common vermin they are here, citizens trying to find crafty ways to offer you as a sacrifice to eldritch beings and not caring much whether you are alive or undead, and the monstrous results of transmutation mishaps crawling and oozing in the city sewers.

Various stores present in the city offer a wide range of alchemical ingredients, magical elixirs, ritual implements, and of course there is a necromancer's shop with an assortment of zombielike husks, some of their emaciated bodies covered in arcane runes. Dark elves from the southeast and various outsiders of dubious morality often visit the city to buy these goods.

The shopkeeper assures her customers that all the husks are well-preserved, the stench is negligible, and of course that the husks won't even bite your ear off if controlled with strong enough spells.

The sole fact that such shop exists means that there is an economic demand for husks and zombies, but what would be the reason of anyone buying them?

Comment: This seems to be an entirely opinion-based question. Try to tell us what kind of answers are acceptable, so answers can be judged appropriately. As this question stands, there are any number of answers that would work.

Comment: Welcome! It's not my usual custom to close opinion based queries (because, ultimately, every worldbuilding query has some element of opinion); however, in this question, a ***why***, you are literally soliciting our many & varied opinions. This is a no-no on Stack Exchange. Here we help you build your world; we don't serve as a survey pool. Please do review the [tour] and [help] to get a better idea how this forum works!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you ever heard about slaves? They're the worst. They don't speak the language, they're recalcitrant, they need to be feed and drink. And worst think, they have mind on their own and sometimes mumble something under their nose about rebellion.

But Worry no longer my friend!

Here are the zombies. Calm like a dead body. Because they are a dead body. No need to feed them. They don't need to defecate and when not in use? Store them in the broom closet.

We got them all. You like fancy diners and Black elves serving most exquisite food? We got you! You have some heavy loads in the docks that need to be moves? We have ogres. And if they get crushed because you are to cheap to buy some PPE? Who cares? They were dead in the first place!

Comment: Amazon would like to buy all your stock. They already make their employees pee in a bottle and refuse pregnant women any additional break.

Answer (score 1):

Cheap LABOUR!

No Zombie's worker union.

No need to pay severance.

Hazard pay? pay at all???

They don't ask questions, so if you have a less than "By the books" job to do, they will smuggle the package, no questions asked.

It wouldn't surprise me to see some Royal Edict to regulate them, otherwise they will gain TOO MUCH power.

Answer (score 1):

**They are vessels.**

Pulling an extra dimensional power or dead spirit into our plane is hard enough.  But then how to talk with it?  How to interact with it?  How to keep track of it?   These incorporeal things need something physical to inhabit.  That is what these husks provide - a physical form with preserved human apparatus, suitable for containing a spirit.  From within the husk, dead wizards or demons can interact with the world, reveal their secrets, and do other the other things one hopes for when something is summoned from exotic planes.

Answer (score 1):

Having easily controllable zombies would be a great means of protection and perimeter control.  Disable the spell and you've got a tireless and ever ready sentry at your disposal.

They could also be status/power related should you want those in possession to seem sinister.  Having a whole collection of fallen souls is pretty demented but if it were possible, you know there would definitely be collectors out there.

Answer (score 1):

Golems are expensive! Yes for their price they are a tireless, fast and strong workforce that will undoubtedly pay back their costs but there are also downsides. Its more economical to build large golems that you cant just store in a smaller house and their ungainly size makes them bad servants, especially when considering the costs of making them look good enough to play a waiter for your expensive friends.

But we have a solution! We cant sacrifice your good farmland, or the local golf course, for a large graveyard! It just attracts graverobbers and people want some time off to bury their friends and family. So we the Necromancer's guild offer the deal of an unlifetime! Rather than having decomposed bodies from graves we get them straight feom the prisons, churches and sacrificial centers all around the city! This ensures that our zombies have that fresh and noble blooded complexion. For your kitchens, warehouses, markets and as masked guards the more damaged corpses are perfect. They can work in tight spaces a Golem just cant reach and are economical in storage. They wear out over time but there's an abundance of corpses always ready to replace them! The high quality corpses that can almost pass for alive get good preservation spells on them to make sure they get a solid  couple of years of use where they can serve you and your friends while staying in the background, rather than a lumbering Golem that cant navigate your carefully planned soiré withoit trampling someone. Get yours today!